# Save to Excel strings with '='

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to save my output to an Excel file, but some of the values have `'='` at the beginning of the string.
So while exporting, Excel converts them to formulas, and instead of strings, I have #NAME error in Excel.
I need to save only some columns as text, as I have dates and numerics in other columns, and they should be saved as is.

I've already tried to convert them with the `.astype()` function, but with no result.

```
def create_excel(datadir, filename, data):

    df = col_type_converter(filename, pd.DataFrame(data))

    filepath = os.path.join(datadir, filename + '.xlsx')
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
    writer.save()
    return filepath

def col_type_converter(name, dataframe):
    df = dataframe

    if name == 'flights':
        df['departure_station'] = df['departure_station'].astype(str)
        df['arrival_station'] = df['arrival_station'].astype(str)
        return df

    return df
```

When I'm importing from CSV using the built-in Excel importer, I can make it import values as text.

Is there any way to say to Pandas how I want to import columns?

Answer (score 1):

nvm, you can just pass xlsxwriter options through pandas:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_formulas': False})
```

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#passing-xlsxwriter-constructor-options-to-pandas
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheetwrite